# How to create the date explicitly in java?

Tags: java, date

I have tried this code. I got the output but not the right one...
//Iam getting my answer after the following changes below...

```
    package patternsamp;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Mydate 
    {
    static void test()
    {
    Date da = new Date(5,9,2014,07,00,00);
    System.out.println(da.toGMTString());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
    Mydate.test();
    }
    }
```

//I made the changes like this.....

```
Date da = new Date(114,8,5,12,30,0);

OUTPUT:  5 Sep 2014 07:00:00 GMT
```

This gives me right output... Thanks for your support friends.....

Comment: See `Calendar` <!--->

Comment: Why did you try that code? Why do you think it should do anything other than what it does right now?

Comment: What is your expected output.

Comment: Javadoc: @Deprecated public Date(int year,
                       int month,
                       int date,
                       int hrs,
                       int min,
                       int sec)  (where year and month have weird offsets)

Comment: I expects what I had given as input..  5 sep 2014 07:00:00 GMT

Comment: _Why_ do you expect that?

Comment: What are you saying?? Can you say clearly?? @sotirios

Comment: You have expectations. Where do they come from? Why did you write it that way?

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat, not this Deprecated rubbish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the sep 5 as output, shuold be given as 5-9,
Try using simpledateformat:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
String dateInString = "5-9-2014 07:00:00";
Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

```
Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min, int sec) 

`Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min, sec).`
```

Avoid using Date constructor (to set dates) at all, incase you insist maintain correct order of parameters, your code should look like this:-

```
package patternsamp;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Mydate 
{
static void test()
{
Date da = new Date(114,9,5,07,00,00);
System.out.println(da.toGMTString());
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{  
Mydate.test();
}
```

Note that I am using 114 in the year (and not 2014), since according to doc

`A year y is represented by the integer y - 1900.`

Hence to represent 2014 , you have to `2014-1900`, which is `114`.

Comment: If I try this, I will get right year and what about date and time??

Comment: You should get the right date and time,if not i might have just interchanged the parameters of month and date, change it to `new Date(114,5,9,07,00,00);` .You can read the javadoc link I have provided in the answer, it has specifications of all parameters. But my suggestion would be to not go with setting Date() using constructor.

Comment: Also if you mean you are getting different output on `da.toGMTString()` that is because it is giving output using GMT timezone, use `da.toLocaleString()` this will give you exact date you set using constructor.

Answer (score 0):

if your project imported commons-lang.jar
you can get the Date object from String like this:

```
DateUtils.parseDate("2014-08-20",new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd"})
```

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

So much easier and sensible to use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library rather than the notoriously troublesome bundled java.util.Date and .Calendar classes. To specify a year, you specify a year (`2014` rather than `114`). To specify a month, you specify a month (`9` means September rather than `8`).

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( 2014, 9, 5, 7, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

If you must have a java.util.Date object, convert.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```